# Passing timestamp parameters in SQLAnalyzer to debug stored procedures

Tags: debugging, sql-server-2000

Hi I'm trying to debug a stored procedure through SQL Analyzer and one of the parameters is a timestamp datatype. If I wanted to pass 0x00000001410039E2 through as a parameter how would i do this? When I pass 0x00000001410039E2 I get a string truncation error and when I pass just 1410039E2 I get 0x1410039E20000000?

Edit: @Frans Yes this works but my issue is that in SQLAnalyzer when i right-click and debug when I enter the value in the value textbox I get the error message:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right truncation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug input screen expects you to enter a hexadecimal value. You don't have to enter the 0x in front of this value.

Just enter 00000001410039E2 and it will work.